# Inkscape: How to assign the tool default Fill & Stroke to an existing object?

Tags: inkscape

If I create a new object with a tool, e.g. the rectangle tool, the object will be created with default fill and stroke colors and stroke style.

How to assign these same default values to an already existing object?

Note: I'm aware of a possible workaround, **Paste-Style** (`Shift`+`Ctrl`+`V`), but it requires an object with the default style already existing.